# How To Get first and last date of a particular month week in PHP

Tags: php, date

I am trying to fetch start date and end date of "2nd week February 2020":

```
$week = "02";
$month = "02";
$year = "2020";

$startdateofweek = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('monday second week of February 2020'));
$enddateofweek = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('saturday second week of February 2020'));
```

I want to output as :

```
array("start_week_date"=>"03-02-2020","end_week_date"=>"09-02-2020")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sunday = strtotime('2 sunday February 2020');
$startdateofweek = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('last monday', $sunday));
$enddateofweek = date('d-m-Y', $sunday);
```